# how to do grouped-per-channel(s) convolution in an efficient way in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, convolution

I'm trying to figure out how to do grouped-per-channel(s) convolution in an efficient way in Tensorflow (or an alternative equivalent method, I'm quite new at this)

I would like to perform k filters independently on g 'channel groups' (k*g total).

For example lets say I have a tensor (batch, width, height, channels=6)

I would like to perform k convolutions independently on 3 channel groups [0,1], [2,3], [4,5]. The output of this should be a tensor (batch,width,height, 6*g*k) where the first third channels correspond to the convolutions on the [0,1] group, second third of channels is the [2,3] group, etc..

I've got some hacky way to do this by manually slicing up the groups and the kernel then re-concatenating. It seems to work but is ugly and maybe slow? I see there is a depth-wise convolution function, but this does not seem to do what I want it to...

Here's my current implementation (I'm away from my code, but its basically like this):

```
grp1 = relu(conv2d(in[:, :, :, :2], kernel[:, :, :2, :], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
grp2 = relu(conv2d(in[:, :, :, 2:4], kernel[:, :, 2:4, :], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
grp3 = relu(conv2d(in[:, :, :, 4:], kernel[:, :, 4:, :], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))

conv_1 = tf.concat(3, [grp1, grp2, grp3])
```

For more context, my data is 3 pairs of EO-IR registered images. Channel 0 is visible spectrum intensity, channel 1 is IR intensity, channels 2,3 and 4,5 are similar

Comment: Perhaps you could use `tf.nn.conv3d` (you'd have to reshape the input for this to work)?

Comment: @kww conv3d is not fully supported in tensorflow lite. Also there are subtle differences between conv3d and a group depthwise convolution. Specifically, the padding on conv3d is across all 3 spatial dimensions, whereas standard group convolutions will be only on 2 spatial axis.